# How to generate GUI dynamically using WPF-MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, mvvm

I am working on a wpf application strictly using MVVM. What i want to do is pop up a window which will pop up on a button click.

This window size will be determined dynamically depending upon the input that i have received  from the pervious form submission on button click.
If the input given was 1 then on this window i will have GUI like: (where * represents the boundary)

```
********************************************
  GUI : some textbox and buttons
********************************************

If the input given was 2 :

********************************************
  GUI : some textbox and buttons
********************************************
********************************************
  GUI : some textbox and buttons
********************************************
```

How to do this using MVVM approach ? Should i code for it  using c# (because the input will be given dynamically)

What i have done is (tableView.xaml, on which will contain the GUI i shown you previously):

```
<UserControl x:Class="DBPythonAndXmlGenerator.View.tableView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DBPythonAndXmlGenerator.ViewModel"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:DBPythonAndXmlGenerator.converters"
             >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:Table x:Key="TableCoverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>                
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And my button click function (MVVM) is below:

```
 public ICommand SavePersonCommand
  {
            get
            {
                if (savePersonCommand == null)
                    savePersonCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action(SaveExecuted), new Func<bool>(SaveCanExecute));
                return savePersonCommand;
            }
  }
public bool SaveCanExecute()
  {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(DB_Col.DbName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(DB_Col.NumTables);
  }
public void SaveExecuted()
  {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Saved: {0} {1} ", DB_Col.DbName, DB_Col.NumTables));
   }
```

How to render data in this Grid dynamically using c# follwing MVVM If my approach is right?

Comment: Self promotion plug: sounds like you're after modeless dialog boxes, I wrote [an article about them](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM) on the Code Project site.

Comment: @MarkFeldman tahnsk for the answer but you have discussed about DialogBoxes...Please see the question again.

Comment: xavxav you stated you need to "pop up a window" which I read to mean a modeless dialog box i.e. a top-level window you can interact with at the same time as the parent window and one that will also close if the parent window is closed, which my article does cover in detail. If this isn't quite what you're after then please clarify your specific requirements and I'll do my best to suggest alternate technologies. Cheers!